# Изменить атрибут src img

Tags: javascript

На сайте имеется блок `< div id='recentpostsae' >` с последними публикациями. В нем нужно изменить src img, с 's72-c' на 's150-c', в данный момент src имеет вид `https://site.ru/радномные_числа/s72-c/kartinka.png`

Как можно это реализовать с помощью js?

На другом сайте скинули вариант, но он не рабочий

```
$(function(){
    let images = $('#recentpostsae  img');
    images.each(function(){
       let s = $(this).attr('src');
       s = s.replace('s72-c','s150-c');
       $(this).attr('src',s);
})
})
```

Скрипт "последние публикации"

```
var numfeed = 5;
var startfeed = 0;
var urlblog = "https://";
var charac = 65;
var urlprevious, urlnext;

function arlinafeed(e, t) {
    for (var n = e.split("<"), r = 0; r < n.length; r++) - 1 != n[r].indexOf(">") && (n[r] = n[r].substring(n[r].indexOf(">") + 1, n[r].length));
    return n = n.join(""), n = n.substring(0, t - 1)
}

function showrecentpostsae(e) {
    var t, n, r, a, i, s = "";
    urlprevious = "", urlnext = "";
    for (var l = 0; l < e.feed.link.length; l++) "previous" == e.feed.link[l].rel && (urlprevious = e.feed.link[l].href), "next" == e.feed.link[l].rel && (urlnext = e.feed.link[l].href);
    for (var d = 0; d < numfeed && d != e.feed.entry.length; d++) {
        t = e.feed.entry[d], n = t.title.$t;
        for (var l = 0; l < t.link.length; l++)
            if ("alternate" == t.link[l].rel) {
                r = t.link[l].href;
                break
            }
        i = "content" in t ? t.content.$t : "summary" in t ? t.summary.$t : "", a = "media$thumbnail" in t ? t.media$thumbnail.url : "https://3.bp.blogspot.com/-BHuXHny1kOk/VXrkSyxKCjI/AAAAAAAACas/pZLJAEUDtds/s1600/no-image.png", s += "<div class='recentpostel'>", s += "<a href='" + r + "' target='_blank'><img src='" + a + "' /></a>", s += "<h6><a href='" + r + "'>" + n + "</a></h6>", s += "<p>" + arlinafeed(i, charac) + "...</p>", s += "</div>"
    }
    document.getElementById("recentpostsae").innerHTML = s, s = "", s += urlprevious ? "<a href='javascript:navigasifeed(-1);' class='previous'>&#10144;</a>" : "<span class='noactived previous'>&#10144;</span>", s += urlnext ? "<a href='javascript:navigasifeed(1);' class='next'>&#10144;</a>" : "<span class='noactived next'>&#10144;</span>", s += "<a href='javascript:navigasifeed(0);' class='home'>Обновить</a>", document.getElementById("recentpostnavfeed").innerHTML = s
}

function navigasifeed(e) {
    var t, n; - 1 == e ? (t = urlprevious.indexOf("?"), n = urlprevious.substring(t)) : 1 == e ? (t = urlnext.indexOf("?"), n = urlnext.substring(t)) : n = "?start-index=1&max-results=" + numfeed + "&orderby=published&alt=json-in-script", n += "&callback=showrecentpostsae", incluirscript(n)
}

function incluirscript(e) {
    1 == startfeed && removerscript(), document.getElementById("recentpostsae").innerHTML = "<div id='recentpostload'></div>", document.getElementById("recentpostnavfeed").innerHTML = "";
    var t = urlblog + "/feeds/posts/default" + e,
        n = document.createElement("script");
    n.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript"), n.setAttribute("src", t), n.setAttribute("id", "arlinalabel"), document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(n), startfeed = 1
}

function removerscript() {
    var e = document.getElementById("arlinalabel"),
        t = e.parentNode;
    t.removeChild(e)
}
onload = function() {
    navigasifeed(0)
};
```

Comment: Вариант рабочий. Наверное, вы его не правильно применяете. Покажите, как и когда вы его используете?

Comment: код рабочий, хотя его и можно записать короче `$('#recentpostsae  img').attr('src', (i,old)=>old.replace('s72-c','s150-c'))`. Скорее всего он просто вызывается до того момента, когда необходимые элементы появляются в разметке.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko  в теме указал скрипт с которым пытаюсь использовать его

Comment: @Grundy не работает. я в теме добавил скрипт "последние публикации ", с которым пытаюсь использовать

Comment: Вам надо добавить ваш код в функцию `showrecentpostsae` в самый конец, после `document.getElementById("recentpostsae").innerHTML = ...`.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko Спасибо большое, работает)

Comment: Опубликуйте ответом. Может, кому-то в будущем пригодится.

Comment: @Grundy Вам то же спасибо, за оптимизацию кода)

Comment: @Josh93, скрипт похож на результат сборки. если ты действительно руками пишешь такой код - это печально